# Compile architecture error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I try to compile an xcode project and get this error:

```
CreateUniversalBinary /Users/yosifz8gmailcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birthday-exrjvwtlolewnqautwqzjjlvkpit/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/birthday.app/birthday normal "armv7 armv7"
cd /Users/yosifz8gmailcom/Desktop/birthday
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
lipo -create /Users/yosifz8gmailcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birthday-exrjvwtlolewnqautwqzjjlvkpit/Build/Intermediates/birthday.build/Debug-iphoneos/birthday.build/Objects-normal/armv7/birthday /Users/yosifz8gmailcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birthday-exrjvwtlolewnqautwqzjjlvkpit/Build/Intermediates/birthday.build/Debug-iphoneos/birthday.build/Objects-normal/armv7/birthday -output /Users/yosifz8gmailcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birthday-exrjvwtlolewnqautwqzjjlvkpit/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/birthday.app/birthday

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo: /Users/yosifz8gmailcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birthday-exrjvwtlolewnqautwqzjjlvkpit/Build/Intermediates/birthday.build/Debug-iphoneos/birthday.build/Objects-normal/armv7/birthday and /Users/yosifz8gmailcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/birthday-exrjvwtlolewnqautwqzjjlvkpit/Build/Intermediates/birthday.build/Debug-iphoneos/birthday.build/Objects-normal/armv7/birthday have the same architectures (armv7) and can't be in the same fat output fileCommand /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1
```

Any idea why it give me this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to changing the value of the Valid Architecture found in **Project > Build Settings > Architectures** from the default `armv6 armv7` to `armv7`. Hope this will helps.

Comment: try to set `armv6 armv7` to `armv6`

Comment: I already see corrupted project.pbxproj. So if you can't change Archs from Xcode, open your project.pbxproj with TextEdit (or another editor), and check it manually. Search for 'ARCHS' key and see whats wrong here. The defaults line should be : ARCHS = "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)";